# Pandas SQL equivalent for 'not equal' clause

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I do not see this in the SQL comparison documentation for Pandas. What would be the equivalent of this SQL in Pandas?

```
select a.var1, a.var2, b.var1, b.var2
from tablea a, tableb b
where a.var1=b.var1 
and a.var2=b.var2
and a.var3 <> b.var3
```

I have the merge code as follows:

```
df = pd.merge(a, b, on=['VAR1','VAR2'], how='inner')
```

How do I incorporate the 'not equal' portion?

```
and a.var3 <> b.var3
```

Comment: after `merge` add `df.loc[df.var3_y!=df.var3_x,:]` :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can query the resulting frame:

```
a.merge(b, on=['VAR1','VAR2']).query('VAR3_x != VAR3_y')
```

Comment: Not often I see you answering a simple question ;-)

Comment: Not often I see you answering a simple question :-)+1

Comment: `!=` being the python equivalent of `<>`